# Enviando arquivos via ajax para WebMethod

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, webmethods

Boa tarde! Eu estou tentando enviar arquivos via `ajax` para um `WebMethod` em `c#`, mas fico recebendo como retorno minha página inteira de html

**Javascript**

```js
//Upload de arquivos
$('#upload').change(function () {
    var fileUpload = $("#upload").get(0);
    var files = fileUpload.files; 

    // Create FormData object  
    var fileData = new FormData();
    // Looping over all files and add it to FormData object  
    for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
        fileData.append(files[i].name, files[i]);
    }  

    //chamando o webmethod
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: './Index.aspx/UploadArquivos',
        data: fileData,
        contentType: false, // Not to set any content header  
        processData: false, // Not to process data
        success: function (response) {
            console.log(response);
        }
    });
});
```

**WebMethod**

```cs
[WebMethod]
public static string UploadArquivos(FormDataCollection formData)
{
    //do stuff
    Debug.WriteLine("Worked");
    return "Response";
}
```

Eu estou executando outra chamada `ajax` na mesma página e ela funciona corretamente, mas essa que estou fazendo nem para no breakpoint que coloquei dentro do WebMethod. **O que estou fazendo de errado?**

Acredito que o problema seja em algum dos argumentos na hora da chamada, ou até o tipo de dado que estou esperando no meu `webmethod` (talvez não seja um `FormDataCollection`?), mas já revirei a internet inteira e não encontro a solução do meu problema...

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Você tem certeza que está chamando o endereço correto? `'./Index.aspx/UploadArquivos` me parece que você está fazendo o request para uma outra página que não possui o `WebMethod` e está retornando o seu `Response` padrão incluíndo a `MasterPage`

Comment: Sim, inclusive é o mesmo endereço da outra requisição ajax da página... Dei uma pesquisada mais a funda e parece que é porque o webmethod espera um `json`... Então ele não entra no método

Comment: De onde você concluiu que ele espera um json?